# Sending bold/colored messages on IRC through a PHP bot

Tags: php, bots, irc

I have a slightly special PHP bot of my own design which has only one very simple purpose : It reads the contents of a one line .txt file and writes it on IRC. Nothing more, nothing less.

This is how the bot reads the file then writes to IRC :

```
$custom_message = file_get_contents($file_path);
fputs($irc_socket,$custom_message."\r\n");
```

The code is that simple, there's nothing else to it, it's just those two lines running in a loop. This is working perfectly so far. It executes all the commands I want, using privmsg or whatever else.

My issue is that I can not get the bot to write messages with bold or colors in them. Here are the ways I attempted which didn't work :

```
privmsg Nickname 0x02test
privmsg Nickname \u0002test
privmsg Nickname \0x02test
privmsg Nickname \002test
privmsg Nickname \x035test
privmsg Nickname \x02test
```

All of these send a message to Nickname containing exactly what is written in them, non bolded.

I must be missing something here, maybe it's file_get_contents() or fputs() escaping characters in ways I'm not figuring out, perhaps something going on with the encoding of my .txt file (currently utf-8, tried others), or perhaps me just inputting the wrong codes to get bold or colors to work ?

Hopefully someone knows !

Thanks in advance,
Eric B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` is reading the file byte by byte and then you are writing those bytes to the socket. It's not interpreting your escape sequences.

If you want to send the actual `0x02` byte you will have to have that byte in the file.

In PHP you can write it by using `fputs($fp, chr(0x02))`.